# kubectl logs "no preferred addresses found" for a specific container in a pod

Tags: logging, kubectl

```
~$ kubectl logs  vsphere-csi-controller-0 -n kube-system
Error from server (BadRequest): a container name must be specified for pod vsphere-csi-controller-0, choose one of: [csi-attacher vsphere-csi-controller liveness-probe vsphere-syncer csi-provisioner]
```

So I specified the container with the `-c` option.

```
~$ kubectl logs  vsphere-csi-controller-0 -n kube-system -c csi-attacher
Error from server: no preferred addresses found; known addresses: []
```

Any guidance on why this is not working?

Comment: By the way is this also happened when you tried to get a log from a pod which contains only one container?

Comment: that worked:
#kubectl logs  coredns-6557d7f7d6-tlxlj -c coredns -n kube-system
.:53
2020-04-22T21:19:19.358Z [INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = 599b9eb76b8c147408aed6a0bbewe69
2020-04-22T21:19:19.358Z [INFO] CoreDNS-1.5.0
2020-04-22T21:19:19.358Z [INFO] linux/amd64, go1.12.2, e3f9a80
CoreDNS-1.5.0
linux/amd64, go1.12.2, e3f9a80
$

Answer (score 2):

I believe this was already discussed in [vsphere-cloud-controller-manager pod crashes with error](https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-vsphere/issues/299).

As per frapposelli:

> This was triaged also during the monthly vSphere provider call and it
>   was pointed out that there might be a fix for this behavior in 1.16,
>   see kubernetes/kubernetes#75229

Also there is a confirmation in 1.17.3 this issue is no longer presents: [github answer](https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-vsphere/issues/299#issuecomment-596575451)

You provided not much info in question, but hope this will help you in  further resolution